# Can an HTML button call an MVC Controller Action method

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Can I write this code for calling an MVC Controller and Action method?

```
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Create", "StudentInfo") %> '"/>
```

Comment: This question could be improved by including more of the code surrounding the line in question. It would be helpful to know whether or not this tag is within a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using the onclick handler may work, it relies unnecessarily on JavaScript. You may find using a form submission to be cleaner:

```
<form action="<%: Url.Action("Create", "StudentInfo") %>" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```